# Ветром сдуло в кювет автомобили. Нужно ли брать в кавычки "сдуло"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Ветром сдуло в кювет автомобили.* Нужно ли брать глагол в кавычки?

Comment: объясните,что навело вас на эту мысль.

Answer (score 1):

**Кавычки не нужны, слово употреблено в прямом значении**, например: два автобуса сдуло ветром в Ростовской области, ветром сдуло крышу с одного из корпусов больницы.